# radio buttons int html5 form - zoom issue

Tags: css, html, radio-button, zooming

So I've heard people talk about things that hate to resize, and that radio buttons are one of them. As such, I was curious if there was a work-around? textareas don't resize nice when using rows/columns, but do when you use width. I tried a similar approach and gave my radio inputs a heights, but didn't 'fix' zoom issue.

And so here I am wondering if there's a fix of sorts for this. I have a fluid layout so it's fine, but it turns out quite bad '~'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a styled replacement (a plus is that you can have the look you want), almost like jQuery Mobile does. It's not that hard.

Some things to give you kickstart:

1. Hide the original input with javascript;
2. Insert your markup to generate the "fake" input;
3. Wireup the events on your replacement to activate or deactivate the original input with the `click`, `focus` and `blur` events.

Also, there are a lot of plugins that can do it for you, like http://www.azurem.com/jqf1/

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons look and feel are usually determined by the OS, as such, it's quite hard to resize them.

A good alternative would be to fake it with an image.